# django-allauth restrict social login to registered users

Tags: django, authentication, django-allauth

What is the recommended way to restrict social login to registered users?

As it is any user with a social account gets passed as authenticated after signing into a social site (google, facebook, etc) even though they aren't registered with my secure site.

Lets assume I'm using the default `domain/accounts/login` templates.  If we can sort it out with those I can make it work my forms or templates.

Hopefully someone else has done this so I don't have to reinvent the wheel here....

I can post any code if you like.

Comment: If look at [this](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#creating-and-populating-user-instances) it seems you can override the return value of the method `is_open_for_signup(self, request)` to disable signup with social auth.

Comment: @dirkgroten I don't think signup is happening when they login through the social links on the default login page.  I think this because I do not see their user accounts in the `/admin` portal under users.  Am I wrong to assume they would register here?